# How to change the port of asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, port

I have a problem which I can't handle. I want to make an intranet asp.net site and there will be 3 account types, one of them is Admin account(it has it's own page). So I want that page to be in another port.

Comment: i would say that, that is not possible. you would have to split up your application into 2 seperate applications

Comment: @thefiloe are you sure that there is no any another way, if yes how can i seperate my application

Comment: i am quite sure. but i am no expert.

Comment: http traffic is generally port 80. Maybe you should use subdomains - `www.example.com` becomes `www.admin.example.com` if you are authenticated.

Comment: @Ravshanjon there is no need to give admin his own port. Can you explain the reasoning behind this?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Sorry for the late answer, but it was a non-tech guy responsible for the project who asked this. :)